# The "Teacher" badge seems to be applied inappropriately on occasion

Tags: discussion, badges

I noticed that someone had the ["Teacher"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1/teacher) badge, which states to be for answering a question with a score of 1 or more. I suppose that's really for "first (successful) answer".

Because the answer indicated had a score of −3, and in fact *no answers* with non-negative scores.

So shouldn't this badge be cancelled?  (I know, it doesn't work that way now.) It is a one-shot determination, so if the answer happens to rise *momentarily* positive (the first vote was up, followed by two downs, for example, with the eventual average being 2 downs for each up) it is awarded, when that would seem to be "mistaken".

For many people, it might get re-awarded to a different answer. In general, I think you shouldn't be too quick to award it, but should wait for the average voting to show. Otherwise, why bother at all? Just say it's for answering, period.

Comment: The badge is simple as it is now. It encourage the user to keep posting answers right after posting the first answer. No need to complicate it, in my opinion.

Comment: @arjafi no it's not. This question is about changing the badge, not about how it works

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe. But part of the question is, "So shouldn't this badge be cancelled?" I interpreted this as shouldn't _that particular Teacher badge_ be cancelled, but perhaps this was a misinterpretation.

Comment: "So shouldn't this badge be cancelled?" - we don't do that. If a badge was earned in good faith (i.e. wasn't won by fraud) we do not take it away. That this person has the badge means that at some point in time they had the criteria to get it awarded. Would you take a gold medal off an Olympic champion because they are now old and can't win anything?

Answer (score 5):

No need to complicate it, plus, some points to consider which you might have missed:

- The Teacher badge (as all badges except Informed) is not awarded instantly. It is awarded by a scheduled task, which run every few minutes (maybe 5, 10, or 15 not sure but it doesn't really matter) which find relevant answers and award the badge. So after getting the first upvote the badge is not awarded on spot. And in the first few minutes, most voting occurs anyway.
- You suggest to "wait for the average voting to show", but it can take long hours, days, weeks, and even more. Many times the votes arrive very slowly. This criteria is unclear and confusing.

All in all, this is a small "nice to have" badge. It encourage people to keep posting answers. No need to change or abort it.

Comment: Two minds... :)

Comment: Hmm, as described, it could have the first (anomolous up) vote just moments before the batch runs. So it would work better if it made sure there was a full period before considering.  Encourage: the person who inspired this *should not* be encouraged from posting more like his existing posts.

Comment: @JDługosz your assumption that the first upvote is usually "anomolous" is just wrong. Of course it happens, but as far as I can tell it's quite rare. (If not very rare)

Answer (score 4):

Badges are awarded in batches and once a post mets a certain condition it gets awarded the badge. That is okay as far as I am concerned, no one is really hurt by this.

It is just a single, easy to get badge for posting your first positive scoring answer. Would you really want to take it away if a post at +1 receives a downvote after a year? That doesn't seem useful to me.

Comment: You were faster this time...

Comment: *But only this time... ARGHH*

Comment: Not after a year, but after 10 minutes?

Comment: It does that already since they are awarded in batches. It will always take some time before it is awarded. In the mean time, voting can be corrected.